# Screen sharing difficultys

Tags: sharing

From my computer enabled sharing and enter vnc://chungus.local The link it gave me into vnc viewer on my phone and it doesn't connect it says
Invalid endpoint: port not correctly specified.
I do not understand what I've done for it to not work
Ubuntu 20.04.4lts

Comment: I am afraid we cannot understand what you did try and what did not work, so also we cannot understand why it's not working. If you add details on what you tried, and how it proceeded, there will be a better chance of help.

Comment: @vanadium what information do I need to provide I gave all of the information I thought might be needed